# Angular New router's ng-link always creates href as "." for md-button

Tags: angularjs

I don't know what the deal is with navigating to the schedule route

```
$router.config([
            { path: '/', component: { main: 'login'} },
            { path: '/home', component: { main: 'home' } },
            { path: '/schedule/:id', component: { main: 'schedule' } },           
        ]);
```

When I use ng-link it is always just a period, or errors out and shows no href, when its rendered

I have tried:

```
ng-link="schedule"
ng-link="schedule({id: home.selectedSchedule.id})"
ng-link="main:schedule"
ng-link="main:[schedule]"

<md-button class="md-raised" ng-link="home">Open Schedule</md-button>

<a class="md-raised md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-link="schedule" href="." aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"><span class="ng-scope">Open Schedule</span><div class="md-ripple-container"></div></a>
```

The home route also does the same thing

The viewport declaration:

```
<div class="main">
    <div ng-viewport="main"></div>
</div>
```

As  workaround I am getting it to work with this, but it throws an error in `$router.recognize(href)`:

```
ng-href="./#/schedule/{{home.selectedSchedule.id}}"
```

Comment: **NOTE** href will not created on the buttons..

Comment: it actually does create an href for the button but it is just ".". I just tried with an <a> and it does the same thing...I know angular is doing something with it becuase when I mess up the stuff within ng-link no href is generated

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
ng-link="main:schedule({id: home.selectedSchedule.id})"
```